# Doctrine 2 cli Shortcut

Tags: doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

I am integrating Doctrine 2 in my current CodeIgniter 3 project
In command-line,when using doctrine command, for example creating database schema from an entity I usually do this.

```
$ ./application/vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Is it possible to create a shortcut for it so that in command line, instead of typing the whole path,

```
$ ./application/vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

I will just type

```
$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:create,
```

if possible, any ideas on how to do this?

I tried this code

```
export  PATH=${PATH}:/application/vendor/bin/doctrine
```

Doesn't work.Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The code you aim to type is still too long to be practical.
I'd recommend using **shell aliases**, e.g.:

```
alias dud='php bin/console orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql'
alias duf='php bin/console orm:schema-tool:update --force'
```

Then I just run:

```
dud
```

And entities <=> database diff is shown. Then if everything works, I update the database by:

```
duf
```